# Generate picturebox dynamically

Tags: vb.net, button, picturebox

I have a product table it contain:
Id_product
Description
Price
Image

So I create a form , I add a panel , I want to generate picturebox for all  product that I have in table product in panel
the picturebox.image=image(product table) and i want add a label for each picturebox that contain price

So what is the tool that allow me do this .

Comment: You don't need a tool besides Visual Studio. Perhaps a User Control. Look for add controls at runtime. Make an attempt and if it doesn't work, post your code and get help fixing it.

Comment: Based on the *names* you're using, the UI framework seems to be Winforms. Consider a ListView (it can handle Images and Text without much effort, with 4 different views selectable just changing a property), a DataGridView (it can handle DataTables that contain Image information, both in the old `Image` format and as a byte array blob). If you instead prefer a *personalized* view, create a UserControl that can present the Images in a *special* (custom) way. A TableLayoutPanel (or FlowLayoutPanel) can be used to organize and scale the presentation of these objects.